# Python Checker: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python-3.x, passwords

I am really confused as to why I keep on getting this Error,

```
password_strength['has_upper'] = False
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

,because I have been changing the code around and I still don't understand. I am trying to make a python password checker and I've looked at all other questions and none of them have helped me.

The code is:

```
def Check():#menu function. Checks a password
global score
print ('Enter a password')
score = 0#sets the score to zero

while True:
    password = input('Password: ... ')
    if 7 <= len(password) < 24:
        break
    else:
        print ('The password must be between 8 and 24 characters.')

password_scores = {0:'Horrible', 5:'Weak', 10:'Medium', 15:'Strong'}#Choses the strength
password_strength = ['has_upper', 'has_lower', 'has_num']

if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
    password_strength['has_upper'] = True#checks if the password has a capital letter
    score=+5
else:
    password_strength['has_upper'] = False
score=-5#Taking away 5 points from the score

if re.search(r'[a-z]', password):
    password_strength['has_lower'] = True#checks if the password has a lower case letter
    score=+5
else:
    password_strength['has_lower'] = False
score= -5

if re.search(r'[0-9]', password):
    password_strength['has_num'] = True#Checking if the password has any numbers
    score=+5
else:
    password_strength['has_num'] = False
score=-5

score = len([b for b in password_strength.values() if b])#comparing the score against the strength

print ('Password is %s' % password_scores[score])#prints how strong the password is
print ("Score is: " + str(score))
```

Please could you give any suggestions or ideas what may be the problem, this would be appreciated. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing lists:

```
['value1','value2']
```

with dictionaries:

```
{'key1' : 'value1','key2' : 'value2'}
```

A list has a numeral key (position) and a dictionary can have a string as a key. Initialize your password_strength as a dictionary, and it will work:

```
password_strength = {'has_upper' : False, 'has_lower' : False, 'has_num': False}
```

Comment: I've changed the password_strength as you've shown but I'm getting,print ('Password is %s' % password_scores[score])#prints how strong the password is
KeyError: 2, as traceback.

Comment: Change the line above that to:
score = len([b for _,b in password_strength.items() if b])

Comment: Or just remove that line, as i see the score is already defined earlier

Comment: I've removed the line. But now I'm getting the feedback, Score is:2 when I am asking my code to add 5 to the score. Is this right?

Comment: I mean remove the line. score = len([b for b in password_strength.values() if b])#comparing the score against the strength Also, change all score =+ 5 to score += 5, same for -. For the rest, just look into your code to debug. Print outputs at different places to see what the values of variables are at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code a bit :

```
import re

def Check():  # menu function. Checks a password
    global score


print('Enter a password')
score = 0  # sets the score to zero

while True:
    password = input('Password: ... ')
    if 7 <= len(password) < 24:
        break
    else:
        print('The password must be between 8 and 24 characters.')

password_scores = {0: 'Horrible', 5: 'Weak', 10: 'Medium', 15: 'Strong'}  # Choses the strength
password_strength = {'has_upper':'0','has_lower':'0','has_num':'0'}

if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
    score = +5
    password_strength['has_upper'] = score  # checks if the password has a capital letter

else:
    score = -5  # Taking away 5 points from the score
    password_strength['has_upper'] = score

if re.search(r'[a-z]', password):
    score = +5
    password_strength['has_lower'] = score  # checks if the password has a lower case letter

else:
    score = -5
    password_strength['has_lower'] = score

if re.search(r'[0-9]', password):
    score = +5
    password_strength['has_num'] = score  # Checking if the password has any numbers

else:
    score = -5
    password_strength['has_num'] = score

score = sum(password_strength.values())  # comparing the score against the strength
print(score)

print('Password is %s' % password_scores[score])  # prints how strong the password is
print("Score is: " + str(score))
```